# Specify environmental variables as commandline parameter in a debug session of VisualStudio C#

Tags: c#, debugging, environment-variables, command-line-arguments

I want to use an environment variable as a commandline parameter in a debug session.
So Project Properties->Debug->Command line arguments: %TEMP% gives me not the temp path as a parameter rather than the string "%TEMP%".

Of course I could resolve the environment variable to a path programmatically or copy past the correct path.
But I want just to know, if an envvariable works and when, how it works?!

Does someone know how I can specify an envvar as a commandline parameter in VS debug commandline arguments?

Answer (score 0):

If the program is launched by visual studio then it inherits VS's environment variables. VS gets its environment variables when it starts. So:

1. Change/set the environment variable
2. Restart Visual Studio
3. Launch/debug your program

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want to have a specific envvar. I want to specify an envvar as a commandline parameter in a debug session.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your local environment variables for debugging in code. In your main entry point you can define as many enviroment variables as you like.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    #if DEBUG
    string path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("path");
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("path", path + @";c:\foo");
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("temp", @"c:\bar");
    #endif

    new Program();
}
```

Together with that [`#if` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) this code will also only compiled if you have a debug build. On release builds this code will be skiped (if you don't change your default settings of your project).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and define few lauch enviroments in `launchSettings.json` file.
It works both for asp.net web projects and console applications